# Show background image out of the div

Tags: html, css, background

http://www.gardencrafts.co.uk/index.htm

In the above link, the background has a leaf going on to the middle of the body! What I want is to separate this entire image into three sections. The header, content & finally the footer. I cropped the needed part for the header but, the thing is the leafs give the background image a height of 600px. The header is 150px in height so the excess part of the background is hidden.

I tried the Overflaw in CSS to show and it din't work. How can I get the image to show it's entire content without changing the height of the header div?

This is the CSS code for the current header DIV..

```
  #header{
background-image: url(../images/top-bg.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 1000px;
height: 200px;
overflow: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved in many ways, here's one of these solutions:

Give the `#body` the full original `background-image` of the page, which includes the falling leaf.

With the right `background-position`, you can merge the top half part of the `#header` with the bottom half part of the `#body`.

Check it out: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AliBassam/BmW4C/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
</div>
<div id="body">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header
{
    background-image:url("https://twitter.com/images/resources/twitter-bird-white-on-blue.png");
    width:300px;
    height:150px;
    border-style:none;
    border-left-style:solid;
    border-right-style:solid;
    border-color:yellow;
}
#body
{
    background-image:url("https://twitter.com/images/resources/twitter-bird-white-on-blue.png");
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-position: 0px -150px;
    border-style:none;
    border-left-style:solid;
    border-right-style:solid;
    border-color:red;
}
```

However, this will allow the `background-image` to repeat itself (if you don't stop it), which will show another leaf afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to apply that background to the parent container of your header but to provide you a better answer we need to give a look at your code